# How to connect MongoDB with Django?

Tags: django, mongodb

I am using **MySQL** as my primary database in Django. Now I want to switch to **MongoDB** as my database. How can I connect to MongoDB in Django?

Answer (score 1):

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost_address:port_Number')
mongo = client.database_name
```